# Resizable Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I know how to use resizable images for normal shaped objects such as button backgrounds, but what about an image like a star?

Is this possible?  Let's take the image below for reference.

```
UIImage *starImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"star"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)];
```

Comment: No, that will distort the star. Do you have a gradient or something inside the star that you are trying to preserve?

Comment: I do not at this point

Comment: `resizeableImageWithCapInsets` is for preserving portions of an image (such as gradients or text) while stretching other portions. If you don't need that functionality, consider stretching normally, as answered below.

Comment: Why use an image? Create a custom `UIView` with a `drawRect:` method that draws the star based on the view's current size.

Comment: @rmaddy I might add a gradient, drop shadow, etc.  I prefer to do these things in Photoshop unless I need to use draw a view

Comment: Scaling a bitmap image doesn't look as nice which is why I suggested a custom view. The custom view can render the picture to the exact size needed. This can include gradients and shadows. It all depends on how you need the end result to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resize an image like the star, you just set the frame to something bigger and make the image fill the image view.

Resizable images do not work for something like a star, but it has to be one that could be resizes vertically and/or horizontally.

[This article](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html) gives a good intro to resizable images.